# Need help optimizing Bootstrap grid for mobile so that the view from desktop is the same on mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

For some reason, these columns are stacking vertically instead of horizontally:

```
                <div id="logos" class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <a href="https://listen.tidal.com/album/107846023">
                            <img class="img-fluid" id="tidal" src={tidal} alt=""></img>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <a href="https://geo.music.apple.com/us/album/_/1460176267?mt=1&app=music&at=1000lHKX">
                            <img class="img-fluid" id="apple" src={apple} alt=""></img>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <a href="https://open.spotify.com/album/6ITBoE1l1zPCtXKOTN12IC">
                            <img class="img-fluid" id="spotify" src={spotify} alt=""></img>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <a href="https://www.pandora.com/artist/various-artists/love-hart-presents-hartfm-explicit/AL2V7Pb7xcg7p74">
                            <img class="img-fluid" id="pandora" src={pandora} alt=""></img>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Not sure what the heck to do here. My CSS rules:

```
#logos {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#tidal {
  display: block;
  width: 5%;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#apple {
  display: block;
  width: 5%;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#spotify {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 4%;
}

#pandora {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 9%;
}
```

I tried everything with re-sizing, but nothing seems to work. I'm not sure if this has to do with the styling, my Bootstrap code, or what.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not working is very simple - there is no `.col-xs-3` class in Bootstrap so it is styled as a normal `div`.

You have 5 options:

```
col-*
col-sm-*
col-md-*
col-lg-*
col-xl-*
```

Just use any of this breaking points and it will fix your problem.

More info: [DOCUMENTATION](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/)

Comment: You have any idea why they're showing up super big in mobile view?

Answer (score 0):

your grid will only be applied to extra small devices as you mention only xs class of grid and I think you are testing this on desktop.

so I removed all you css and just added grid classes for larger device and medium and smaller device.

replace your line where you mentioned columns with this line.

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xl-3">
```

This line will show your grid in all devices same 1 row - 4 column.

And If you do not want to give specific column size you can also specify col only it will auto divide your row in columns.

**Bootstrap grid layout :**

```
+--------------+---------------+--------------+
|    device    | device sizes  | column class |
+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| Extra_small  | [< 576px]     | : col-       |
| Small        | [≥ 576px]     | : col-sm-    |
| Medium       | [≥ 768px]     | : col-md-    |
| Large        | [≥ 992px]     | : col-lg-    |
| Extra_large  | [≥ 1200px]    | : col-xl-    |
+--------------+---------------+--------------+
```

Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/nick4434/pen/xxKROrN?editors=1100) with example.

Comment: There is no `col-xs-*` class in  Bootstrap. The smallest one is `col-sm-*`.

Comment: By the way, if you use the same number of columns on each breakpoint, like in your example, you can simply write `col-sm-3` :)

Comment: yes i know that but for him to understand i have mentioned that.

Comment: You have any idea why the images are showing up much larger in mobile view?

Comment: In my example or yours.

Comment: @BlahZayBlahZay just give col property of bootstrap grid and it will also give grid you want in mobile view.

Comment: I tried it with my code and it works, but the images on mobile are too large

Comment: let me check, It might be your css where the problem is

Comment: no in my example and with your exact css there is no change at all it gives the same view in all sizes. Check My pen.

Answer (score 0):

I removed display flex from the #tidal as .row class has display flex itself & changed the `col-xs` to `col-sm` since it was removed it bootstrap 4, Also `<img>` tag is a self closing tag, you don't need to add `</img>`,

```css
#tidal {
  display: block;
  width: 5%;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#apple {
  display: block;
  width: 5%;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#spotify {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 4%;
}

#pandora {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 9%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div id="logos" class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <a href="https://listen.tidal.com/album/107846023">
                            <img class="img-fluid" id="tidal" src="http://placehold.it/256x256" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <a href="https://geo.music.apple.com/us/album/_/1460176267?mt=1&app=music&at=1000lHKX">
                            <img class="img-fluid" id="apple" src="http://placehold.it/256x256" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <a href="https://open.spotify.com/album/6ITBoE1l1zPCtXKOTN12IC">
                            <img class="img-fluid" id="spotify" src="http://placehold.it/256x256" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <a href="https://www.pandora.com/artist/various-artists/love-hart-presents-hartfm-explicit/AL2V7Pb7xcg7p74">
                            <img class="img-fluid" id="pandora" src="http://placehold.it/256x256" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: You have any idea why the images are showing up super big in mobile view?

Comment: @BlahZayBlahZay , you'll need to manual viewport breakpoints for img width, from what i could see, the `width: 4%` is causing the images to look bigger in mobile view,

Comment: Actually, so on desktop, when I shrink the browser screen, the images stack vertically as opposed to horizontally. Not sure why that's happening.

Comment: Nvm, I got it I think

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the code for Bootstrap 4 grid system. Bootstrap 3's grid system's grid classes are a little bit different from the bootstrap 4's grid classes.

In Bootstrap 4 the newly updated grid classes are,

.col- (For mobile devices) and  .col-xl- (For larger than desktop sizes i.e ≥1200px )

So for mobile size device code, you need to use .col-* class not col-xs-* class.

If you have a problem with images in mobile view, then you can use img-responsive class to the image, it may help you.